# Android Custom Listview view=null issue

Tags: java, listview, scrollview

I have an custom listview and textview,checkbox,edittext on it. I want to iterate my listview row and wanna take textview,checkbox and edittext values. When iteration comes up to end of the page cannot take invisible rows widget values and crashing. I have to scroll down my listview automatically i think. How can I fix this issue?

Note: I have 12 rows but it crashs after 6th row cz cannot see 7th row without scrolldown my listview.

This is my code:

```
public void onSave(View view) {
        ArrayList<String> olcum = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> orneklemebuyukluk = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText et;
        CheckBox chx;
        TextView buyukluk;
        String nitel="0";
        for (int i = 0; i < list_olcum_view.getCount(); i++) {
            view = list_olcum_view.getChildAt(i);
            et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_olcum);
            chx=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_orneklemenitel);
            olcum.add(et.getText().toString());

         }
}
```

Comment: Please, check my code at below

Comment: Where is your adapter and your getView() where you can get the position of the list item? Take a look at [how-to-get-listview-position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014743/how-to-get-listview-position)

Comment: Please remove your answer as I edited your queston and put your code in there-

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: I have 12 rows but it crashs after 6th row cz cannot see 7th row without scrolldown my listview.

public void onSave(View view) {
        ArrayList<String> olcum = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> orneklemebuyukluk = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText et;
        CheckBox chx;
        TextView buyukluk;
        String nitel="0";
        for (int i = 0; i < list_olcum_view.getCount(); i++) {
            view = list_olcum_view.getChildAt(i);
            et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_olcum);
            chx=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_orneklemenitel);
            olcum.add(et.getText().toString());

}
}
```